# Effect of having two consecutive rollback

Tags: transactions, try-catch

I have a class A in Java which calls another method b in class B.  The method b called does a commit.  Then in A, I have a try with 2 catch as below:

```
try {
     does a commit here
} catch (boom) {
     does a rollback here
} catch(baam) {
     does another rollback here
}
```

What I want to know is whether, the 2nd rollback cancels the 1st rollback?  Like the commit changed var x to 20, the 1st rollback change var x to its original value 10 but the 2nd rollback change it back to 20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to rollback something already rolled back, it's simply no operation. Depends on specific API, in modern Java frameworks / application servers it's better to just set setRollbackOnly() flag on the transaction and leave it to application server.

Anyway, here in this case actually only one rollback can be executed. Either Boom exception will occur or Baam exception will occur, they can't happen at once.

Comment: You mean if the try does not work, it will enter either boom or baam.  It cannot enter both catch?

Comment: @tabby : Yes, you can enter only one of them. Only the first matching catch will be executed.